# Use case splitting

Tags: c#, clean-architecture, use-case

Which is best way to split Use Case?

I have the following architecture (Clean Architecture):

```
 - Project.Api
 - - Project.Api.Controllers.TodoController
 - Project.Application
 -- Project.Application.Todos.Commands.CreateTodo
 - Project.Core
 - - Project.Repositories.ITodoRepository
 - - Project.Entities.Todo
```

**CreateTodo** command creates and saves **TODO** through repository.

```
var todo = new Todo(...);
await _todoRepository.Add(todo, cancellationToken);
```

But after creating **TODO**  i need to make other things. For example:

```
 - Schedule notification about added TODO
 - Generate short link for TODO
```

And if i will do it in same command i will get next:

```
var todo = new Todo(...);
await _todoRepository.Add(todo, cancellationToken);

var notification = new Notification(...);
await _notificationRepository.Add(...);

var shortLink = new ShortLink(todo.Id, ...);
await _shortLinkRepository.Add(...);
```

Also other things can have additional logic(try catch, retry politics, validation etc).

And them can be slow, but i want to return result immediately.

I can create worker service for other things but its see not correct and difficult, also its one use-case is it correct to separate it?

How i can solve it?

Comment: Split repository and entities too.  Clean architecture should mean that domains/entities are standalone and should have no knowledge of persistence (load/store)

Comment: read about Mediator Pattern